# R: Group by / loop through one column of data frame

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a data frame df in R, here are first 6 rows of it.

```
df <- data.frame (npi_one = c('n1487','n1952','n1952','n1467','n1467','n1538'),
                  npi_two = c('n1467','n1467','n1487','n1508','n1538','n1508'),
                  weight = c(1,1,2,1,1,1),
                  hee_provn1=c(rep(015171,3),rep(015443,3)))
```

And I want to group by hee_provn1, then do a loop, the code of the first loop is:

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df2 <- filter(df, hee_provn1 == 015171)
df3 <- df2 [,c("npi_one","npi_two")]
l = c(apply(df3,1,c))
G <- graph(l,directed = FALSE)

d <- degree(G)
c <- closeness(G,weight = df2$weight)
b <- betweenness(G, weight = df2$weight)
e <- eigen_centrality(G,weight = df2$weight)$vector

cent_df = data.frame(d,c,b,e)
colnames(cent_df) <- c('degree', 'closeness','betweenness','eigen')
setDT(cent_df, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
setnames(cent_df,1,"npi")
cbind(hee_provn1 = 015171,cent_df)
```

And the result table of the first loop (hee_provn1 == 015171) is

```
   hee_provn1   npi degree closeness betweenness     eigen
1:      15171 n1487      2 0.3333333         0.0 1.0000000
2:      15171 n1467      2 0.5000000         0.5 0.7320508
3:      15171 n1952      2 0.3333333         0.0 1.0000000
```

And the result table of the second loop (hee_provn1 == 015171) is

```
   hee_provn1   npi degree closeness betweenness eigen
1:      15443 n1467      2       0.5           0     1
2:      15443 n1508      2       0.5           0     1
3:      15443 n1538      2       0.5           0     1
```

I am new to R, I don't know how to do the group by and loop according to one column of dataframe.

Also, I want my final result is a big table put all the table together, like:

```
   hee_provn1   npi degree closeness betweenness     eigen
1:      15171 n1487      2 0.3333333         0.0 1.0000000
2:      15171 n1467      2 0.5000000         0.5 0.7320508
3:      15171 n1952      2 0.3333333         0.0 1.0000000
4:      15443 n1467      2       0.5           0     1
5:      15443 n1508      2       0.5           0     1
6:      15443 n1538      2       0.5           0     1
```

And for some reason, I cannot use R package tidyverse, thanks

---

I tried the method from Balter,

```
df <- data.frame (npi_one = c('n1487','n1952','n1952','n1467','n1467','n1538'),
                  npi_two = c('n1467','n1467','n1487','n1508','n1538','n1508'),
                  weight = c(1,1,2,1,1,1),
                  hee_provn1=c(rep(015171,3),rep(015443,3)))

library(igraph)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

final.df <- c()
for(x in unique(df$hee_provn1)){
  df2 <- subset(df, subset = hee_provn1 == x)

  df3 <- df2 [,c("npi_one","npi_two")]
  l = c(apply(df3,1,c))
  G <- graph(l,directed = FALSE)

  d <- degree(G)
  c <- closeness(G,weight = df2$weight)
  b <- betweenness(G, weight = df2$weight)
  e <- eigen_centrality(G,weight = df2$weight)$vector

  result <- data.frame(d,c,b,e)
  setDT(result, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
  setnames(result,1,"npi")
  cbind(hee_provn1 = x,result)
  final.df <- rbind(final.df, result)
}
colnames(final.df) <- c('npi','degree', 'closeness','betweenness','eigen')
```

The result is :

```
     npi degree closeness betweenness     eigen
1: n1487      2 0.3333333         0.0 1.0000000
2: n1467      2 0.5000000         0.5 0.7320508
3: n1952      2 0.3333333         0.0 1.0000000
4: n1467      2 0.5000000         0.0 1.0000000
5: n1508      2 0.5000000         0.0 1.0000000
6: n1538      2 0.5000000         0.0 1.0000000
```

Looks like it is different from my ideal result, how to successfuly keep track of whcih iteration produced it?

Comment: You can just add a column to `result`.  `result <- data.frame(x,d,c,b,e)` since `x` is what you're subsetting on.  Dont forget to change your last line: `colnames(final.df) <- c('hee_provn1','npi','degree', 'closeness','betweenness','eigen')`

Comment: Fyi, your `cbind(hee_provn1 = x,result)` line does not do anything. You need to assign the result. Only the special `set*` functions work without assigning the result. Also, growing things dynamically in a loop is inefficient in R. The R Inferno is a good guide to pitfalls like this http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start over without loading dplyr. Then...

```
library(data.table)
library(igraph)
setDT(df)

# clean bad formatting
df[, `:=`(npi_one = as.character(npi_one), npi_two = as.character(npi_two))]

df[, {
  G = graph_from_edgelist(cbind(npi_one, npi_two), directed = FALSE)
  .(
    v = V(G)$name,
    d = degree(G),
    c = closeness(G, weight = weight),
    b = betweenness(G, weight = weight),
    e = eigen_centrality(G, weight = weight)$vector
  )
}, by=hee_provn1]
```

which gives ...

```
   hee_provn1     v d         c   b         e
1:      15171 n1487 2 0.3333333 0.0 1.0000000
2:      15171 n1467 2 0.5000000 0.5 0.7320508
3:      15171 n1952 2 0.3333333 0.0 1.0000000
4:      15443 n1467 2 0.5000000 0.0 1.0000000
5:      15443 n1508 2 0.5000000 0.0 1.0000000
6:      15443 n1538 2 0.5000000 0.0 1.0000000
```

*How it works*

Data.table syntax is `DT[i, j, by=]` which filters by `i` (not needed here), groups by `by=` and then computes `j`. `j` should evaluate to a list, and `list()` can be written as `.()` as a shorthand.

Why not load dplyr? It's not needed and igraph has enough namespace conflicts already.

---

If you really want to use dplyr, I strongly recommend not using data.table at the same time...

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(igraph)

# fix bad formatting
df %<>% mutate(npi_one = as.character(npi_one), npi_two = as.character(npi_two))

df %>% group_by(hee_provn1) %>% do(with(., {
  G = graph_from_edgelist(cbind(npi_one, npi_two), directed = FALSE)
  data.frame(
    v = V(G)$name,
    d = degree(G),
    c = closeness(G, weight = weight),
    b = betweenness(G, weight = weight),
    e = eigen_centrality(G, weight = weight)$vector
  )
}))

# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   hee_provn1 [2]
  hee_provn1     v     d         c     b         e
       <dbl> <chr> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1      15171 n1487     2 0.3333333   0.0 1.0000000
2      15171 n1467     2 0.5000000   0.5 0.7320508
3      15171 n1952     2 0.3333333   0.0 1.0000000
4      15443 n1467     2 0.5000000   0.0 1.0000000
5      15443 n1508     2 0.5000000   0.0 1.0000000
6      15443 n1538     2 0.5000000   0.0 1.0000000
```

Comment: HI, Frank, if possible, can you show me the code using dplyr?

Comment: @kkjoe Okay, added.

Comment: Thank you, Frank. Sorry, I just found our result is different. If you look at 15443, n1467, you will find your closeness is 0.1666667, however, you can easily find the graph 15543 is a triangle structure with all weight 1, so the measure of n1467 should be same as n1538, as well as n1508. I studied your code very hard, but cannot figure out why

Comment: @kkjoe Op, sorry about that. I should have used `graph_from_edgelist`, not `graph`. I have fixed it in the post and it seems to match now.

Comment: Thank you, sir, it looks perfect now. I put a new question, which adds a new demand - add some single nodes from another table. You are very good at r dataframe, I would be very grateful if you can help me with this, using dyplr, not loop. thank you ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185154/r-igraph-add-single-nodes-to-multiple-graph-from-another-dataframe,

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way I can think of (without recreating your whole code):

```
final.df <- c()
for(x in unique(df$hee_provn1)){
  y <- subset(df, subset = hee_provn1 == x)
  result <- ##do your stuff here with table y
 final.df <- rbind(final.df, result)
}
```

So your subsetting the table for each unique value in hee_provn1, doing your stuff, and then appending a dataframe with your results.

Comment: I tried your method, it's cool and I updated it in the question, but I still don't know how to keep track of which iteration produced the result. thanks

Comment: I commented your original question :)

Comment: I commented this under the OP already, but you might want to have a look at chapter 2 of the R Inferno http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/ It may be counterintuitive, but it's useful to keep in mind when programming with R.